# Why do i get high pitched sounds from my computer?

Tags: windows-7, audio, surround-sound

When I listen from my laptop, the same song is *normal*. but from my PC, its just **high pitched** and painful. please tell me what driver I should install! When i got to properties and update its driver, it says:

> it says driver is up to date but sound is not of great quality.

Also, when I had Ubuntu, the sound was okay.

[image]

Comment: test different speakers? test different media players?

Comment: What is the sound device you are using ?  Onboard the motherboard?  Via the HDMI on a video card? seperate sound card? USB device? Have you checked for the option of an "equaliser" in the Control pannel Sound, or (look close) if there is a specific added audio manager in the control pannel?  Often the windows simple driver that works and comes in updates and all, does not have all the added features of the total sound package that can be installed. The driver is best found at the manufactures site.  get it at the motherboards support site for onboard.

Comment: Also, try to see if you can resolve that unknown device

Answer (score 0):

On some old version of Realtek Control Panel, you had an option to modificate the octave (higher or lower the pitch), but here since you have generic Microsoft driver, that shouldn't affect you.

We miss some information to indicate you correctly the right driver, but since it seems to be an HD Audio Device, you probably need the Realtek HD Audio Codec, which can be downloaded here : http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/